# Why is there errors on my page with google font?

Tags: html

I validate here: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kandglettings-in-hull-are-awful-to-deal-with.com%2F and it show some red error i not know fix.

My site is here: https://www.kandglettings-in-hull-are-awful-to-deal-with.com

Comment: Seeing your html might help.

Comment: 1. What are the errors it lists? 2. What is the HTML that causes those errors? (The errors and markup should be in the question, a question shouldn't require answerers to visit/dissect an external site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you provided says:

> Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.

## Option 1

I used Google Fonts (fonts.google.com) to create an embedding URL for Roboto and Open Sans and its following: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900`.

Now the URL not contain invalid character `|`, so please try that.

In your case:

```
<link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900">
```

---

## Option 2

Or you can simply replace the `|` character with the encoded one `%7C`.

In your case:

```
<link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i%7COpen+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
```